FluentAssertions throws an exception while comparing 2 object models
In an API project, I'm consolidating data from separate external sources. One of these sources returns data in JSON format:
{
    "agency": "SomeAgency",
    "agencyData": {
        "brandColor": "#A70000",
        "cityName": "",
        "countryCode": "BE",
        "email": "",
        "iataCode": "12345678",
        "imageUrl": "",
        "name": "",
        "phoneContact": "",
        "postalCode": "",
        "stateProv": "",
        "street": ""
    },
    "agent": "someone@somewhere.world",
    "agentEmail": "someone@somewhere.world",
    "allowedPassengerUpdates": {
        "document_correction": {
            "allowed": true,
            "allowedPerPassengerType": {
                "ADT": true
            },
            "fieldsToUpdate": [
                "documentID",
                "documentType",
                "fiscalName",
                "citizenshipCountryCode",
                "residenceCountryCode",
                "issuingCountryCode",
                "expirationDate"
            ]
        },
...

I serialize this data into an object model, and use this model for the actual consolidation.
To validate this, I wrote the following unit test:
public void IsJsonValid()
{
    var expectedJson = LoadJson("Example.json");

    //  Generate a base object model using a generalized structure
    var expected = JToken.Parse(expectedJson);

    //  Generating an object model using the defined classes
    var actualModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRetrieveResponse>(expectedJson);

    //  Converting the new object back into json
    var actualJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actualModel);

    //  Generating a new object using a generalized structure
    var actual = JToken.Parse(actualJson);

    //  Comparing the 2
    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}

This approach works fine if the data provider keeps its JSON clean and doesn't start mixing data types throughout the file.
When I execute the test, the comparison (actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected)) throws an exception:

The exception more in detail:

What I should do differently to avoid this issue?
I've included a zipped file of my example project, which only contains the code and JSON data to reproduce the error.

read the messages?

Why do you validate json against json? Why not validate the deserialized model against an expected model?

The messages are regarding an error occurring in FlientAssertions.... The json I receive is valid, so... it looks like a bug in their code base. So the messages aren't exactly useful.

Well, I was looking at a way to validate 2 jsons... the model I'm expecting to use is rather big, didn't fancy the idea of creating a model manually. But I did have a to if examples, so I looked for a way to work with those. I found a couple of solutions that worked in a similar way, and decided to adapt those.
But... what did you have in mind? Perhaps my approach is wrong...
